# How do i fix my Hailstone Sequence Output?

Tags: c

The code is supposed to take 1 command line argument (an integer) and ouput the corresponding Hailstone sequence and it does this sucessfully. However instead of printing just the sequence my code prints the integer and then the sequence.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int Hailstone(int num)

{
if(num % 2 == 0) {
return num /=2;
}
else {
return num = (3 * num) + 1;
}
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int n = atoi(argv[1]);
while (n != 1)
   {
      printf("%d\n", n);
      n = Hailstone(n);
   }
   printf("%d\n", n);
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. According to [Hailstone Number -- from Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HailstoneNumber.html), The initial number is included in the sequence.

Comment: Do you know how i would remove the initial number from my output?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the initial number be printed, you should make your code print only numbers after processed.

Example:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int n = atoi(argv[1]);
   do
   {
      n = Hailstone(n);
      printf("%d\n", n);
   }
   while (n != 1);
   return(0);
}
```